# How to pick end of day in a timezone with daylight savings?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

Given a date, say 2013-03-24, I want to convert it to end of that day in the US/Pacific timezone.  Is there a way to figure out whether the timezone on that specific date in the region is going to be PST or PDT?  BTW, I'm using Java.

I suspect there isn't a way to do this (at least not without querying some database somewhere that knows when timezone transitions are going to happen), but thought I'd check.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Calendar will handle that for you, there's no need to try to sort out the timezone yourself.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dateInServerTZ = format.parse("2013-03-24");
Calendar calInServerTZ = Calendar.getInstance();
calInServerTZ.setTime(dateInServerTZ);
Calendar calInPST = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
calInPST.set(Calendar.YEAR, calInServerTZ.get(Calendar.YEAR));
calInPST.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calInServerTZ.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
calInPST.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calInPST.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calInPST.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
calInPST.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
Date endOfDayPST = calInPST.getTime();
```

You can eliminate a step by parsing into PST, but I felt this example makes it more clear what's going on in the relationship between server time and user time.

This would obviously be more efficient:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
Date dateInPST = format.parse("2013-03-24");
Calendar calInPST = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")); 
calInPST.setTime(dateInPST);
calInPST.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calInPST.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calInPST.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
calInPST.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
```